# Conversion from Unix Time to Java Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, unix-timestamp

The following is driving me crazy, why am I getting the wrong calendar date when converting Unix Time 1386230874 using the code below!!

This should be Thu Dec 5 19:07:54 2013

Output:

```
Comment posted on:Sat Jan 17 11:03:50 EST 1970
```

Code:

```
Calendar facebook_created_time_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));    
facebook_created_time_calendar.setTimeInMillis(1386230874);
out.print("Comment posted on:");
out.println(facebook_created_time_calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Did you try `new Date(1234567...).toString()` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Java works with millisecond timestamps, while Unix time stamps are typically measured in seconds. Multiply the Unix timestamp by `1000L` to get the right time.

Comment: The stupid mistake that I did was to use 1000 multiplied with the unixtime stored as integer, which results in an integer overflow. So the L after the 1000 is important because it promotes the literal to a long and thus forces a long result. (Just for those wondering why there is an L)

Answer (score 3):

Unix measures time as the number of seconds ("1386230" seconds [you went seconds to milliseconds with `setTimeInMillis`] is "16.04433" days) and since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (January 1, 1970 + 16.04 days is Jan 17 it is working) - so try this

```
facebook_created_time_calendar
    .setTimeInMillis(1386230874L * 1000);
```